# Scala: Remove duplicated integers from Vector( tuples(Int,Int) , ...)

Tags: scala, vector, tuples

I have a big size of a vector (about 2000 elements), inside consists of many tuples, `Tuple(Int,Int)`, i.e.

```
val myVectorEG = Vector((65,61), (29,49), (4,57), (12,49), (24,98), (21,52), (81,86), (91,23), (73,34), (97,41),...))
```

I wish to remove the repeated/duplicated integers for every tuple at the index (0), `i.e. if Tuple(65,xx) repeated at other Tuple(65, yy) inside the vector, it should be removed)`

I enable to access them and print out in this method:

```
val (id1,id2) = ( allSource.foreach(i=>println(i._1)),  allSource.foreach(i=>i._2))
```

How can I remove duplicate integers? Or I should use another method, rather than using `foreach` to access my element index at 0

Comment: Does it matter which of `(65, xx)` or `(65, yy)` is removed?

Comment: Both duplicated should be removed from the vector. Thanks!

Comment: So `Vector((65,11),(34,45),(65,22))` should be reduced to `Vector((34,45))` because both duplicates are removed?

Comment: Do you want to preserve the order of elements?

Comment: @jwvh Yes, you are right!

Comment: @Tim Because the data is about 2000 elements, so I will sort them in ascending order for a better view. Thanks!

Comment: If you sort the data first it will make this operation much easier because the duplicates will be adjacent...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove all duplicates, first group by the first tuple and only collect the tuples where there is only one tuple that belongs to that particular key (`_._1`). Then flatten the result.

```scala
myVectorEG.groupBy(_._1).collect{
  case (k, v) if v.size == 1 => v
}.flatten
```

This returns a `List` which you can call `.toVector` on if you need a `Vector`

Answer (score 3):

This does the job and preserves order (unlike other solutions) but is `O(n^2)` so potentially slow for 2000 elements:

```
myVectorEG.filter(x => myVectorEG.count(_._1 == x._1) == 1)
```

This is more efficient for larger vectors but still preserves order:

```
val keep =
  myVectorEG.groupBy(_._1).collect{
    case (k, v) if v.size == 1 => k
  }.toSet

myVectorEG.filter(x => keep.contains(x._1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a distinctBy to remove duplicates.

In the case of `Vector[(Int, Int)]` it will look like this

```
myVectorEG.distinctBy(_._1)
```

Updated, if you need to remove all the duplicates:

You can use `groupBy` but this will rearrange your order.

```
myVectorEG.groupBy(_._1).filter(_._2.size == 1).flatMap(_._2).toVector
```

Comment: I think OP wants to remove ALL duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Another option, taking advantage that you want the list sorted at the end.

```
def sortAndRemoveDuplicatesByFirst[A : Ordering, B](input: List[(A, B)]): List[(A, B)] = {
  import Ordering.Implicits._

  val sorted = input.sortBy(_._1)

  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[(A, B)], previous: (A, B), repeated: Boolean, acc: List[(A, B)]): List[(A, B)] =
    remaining match {
      case x :: xs =>
        if (x._1 == previous._1)
          loop(remaining = xs, previous, repeated = true, acc)
        else if (!repeated)
          loop(remaining = xs, previous = x, repeated = false, previous :: acc)
        else
          loop(remaining = xs, previous = x, repeated = false, acc)

      case Nil =>
        (previous :: acc).reverse
    }

  sorted match {
    case x :: xs =>
      loop(remaining = xs, previous = x, repeated = false, acc = List.empty)

    case Nil =>
      List.empty
  }
}
```

Which you can test like this:

```
val data = List(
  1 -> "A",
  3 -> "B",
  1 -> "C",
  4 -> "D",
  3 -> "E",
  5 -> "F",
  1 -> "G",
  0 -> "H"
)

sortAndRemoveDuplicatesByFirst(data)
// res: List[(Int, String)] = List((0,H), (4,D), (5,F))
```

*(I used **List** instead of **Vector** to make it easy and performant to write the tail-rec algorithm)*