# C++ : Remove duplicated integers from vector<tuples<Int,Int>> without sorting it

Tags: c++, vector, tuples

Basically I want my vector to be unique and not in order as that helps me in calculating distance and determine the best route

This is the instance

```
vector<tuple<int, int>> child_chromosome;
```

this is what I have tried

```
 unordered_set<vector<tuple<int,int>>> s(child_chromosome.begin(), child_chromosome.end());
 child_chromosome.assign(s.begin(), s.end());
```

This doesn't work giving error when debug

```
Error   C2280   'std::_Uhash_compare<_Kty,_Hasher,_Keyeq>::_Uhash_compare(const std::_Uhash_compare<_Kty,_Hasher,_Keyeq> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function    GenAlgoRealLife C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\unordered_set 49
```

Also tried a solution from [Scala: Remove duplicated integers from Vector( tuples(Int,Int) , ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61629312/scala-remove-duplicated-integers-from-vector-tuplesint-int) but to avail as its using a different language & no such attributes(groupBy,filter) exits in C++

Comment: If you try to verbalize what `unordered_set<vector<tuple<int,int>>>` means, in plain English, using as simple words as possible, and whether this is what you're actually trying to do, then the problem should be fairly clear.

Comment: well what the `unordered_set<>` does is convert my vector into set and in set we can remove the duplicates without changing the order [link](https://www.techiedelight.com/remove-duplicates-vector-cpp/) I hope this helps you

Comment: What does `unordered_set<vector<tuple<int, int>>>` mean to you? It does not mean "convert my vector into a set". It means that this object is an unordered set, and the set contains vectors of tuples with two integers. That's what it means, in plain english. Additionally, "unordered" does not mean "the order is not changed". It means that all the contents in the set are in some random order that's completely unspecified, and can be anything. If you open your C++ textbook to the chapter that describes what unordered containers are, is there something there that led you to believe otherwise?

Comment: I'll be honest I haven't read any book and just a beginner also thanks for pointing this out